# Update command not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET userrole ='$userrole' WHERE member_id = '$member_id'";
```

Sometimes it updates and sometimes it does not... i don't know whether the syntax is correct.

userrole and member_id has array of values. The update query is performed for multiple items being checked.

**There is no error in mysql connection or error.... for the first time the update does not happen and after that it happens**

Comment: that is just a line, we need more than that to determine what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about debugging. First, I would check if there is a mysql error to start you off.

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET userrole ='$userrole' WHERE member_id = '$member_id'";
echo mysql_errno($yourmysqlconnection) . ": " . mysql_error($yourmysqlconnection) . "\n"
```

Then doublecheck your $userrole and $memberid Variable. Post your findings here, and we might to help you further

Good Luck,
rAyt

Comment: There is no error in mysql connection or error.... for the first time the update does not happen and after that it happens.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot work, if both variables contain arrays. You need to update the items one by one (or use a clumsy MySql CASE statement, which I won't explain here):

```
foreach ($userrole as $key => $role) {
    $query = "UPDATE members SET userrole ='$role'
              WHERE member_id = '$member_id[$key]'";
    // perform query ...
}
```

Or if only $member_id is an array:

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET userrole ='$userrole'
          WHERE member_id IN ('" . implode(',', $member_id) . "')";
// perform query ...
```

You should further rename your variables to reflect that they are arrays. Just use the plural:

```
$userrole => $userroles
$member_id => $member_ids
```

On more thing: Are these values coming from a HTML form? If yes, [you should really](http://xkcd.com/327/) sanitize them using [`mysql_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php). This can be done for multiple values at once using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$userroles = array_map('mysql_escape_string', $userroles);
$member_ids = array_map('mysql_escape_string', $member_ids);
```

Comment: What error? And could you please append the results of var_dump($userrole) and var_dump($member_id) to your question?

Answer (score 1):

1. Unless you've skipped a bit you're not escaping your inputs - not good!

   `$userrole = mysql_real_escape_string($userrole);`
2. If $member_id is an array, you can't just put it into an update like that.
   I suspect you want something like this (after escaping of course!)

   `$query = "UPDATE members SET userrole ='$userrole' WHERE member_id IN (" . implode(",", $member_id) . ")";`

Comment: This throws an error... actually i am getting the values like 0 1 2 3 without any commas

Comment: If you're getting that them member_id isn't an array - try var_dump($member_id);